# Ionic 3 PayPal integration checkout Issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, paypal, ionic3, paypal-sandbox

I used the
[link from PayPal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/), in which I tried to integrate the PayPal payment gateway with the Ionic 3 application. I could get the event button on the home page. Once the event is triggered by clicking on the button, it opens the login page, after login, the issue is with the checkout page which always shows the cart and the amount to be paid only as $0.01, even after I tried to change the payment amount from the code. I tried by building the app for the android.
Here I present the codes which I used, Kindly advice.

I have added the below code in the index.html

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY--SANDBOX_ID"></script>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var paypal: any; 
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  payPalConfig = {
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
      sandbox: 'MY--SANDBOX_ID',
    },
    commit: true,
    payment:(data, actions) => {
      console.log("data is", data, actions);
      return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {
          transactions: [
            { amount: {
              total: '10.00',
              currency: 'USD'
            } }
          ]
        }
      });
    }
  }
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  payButtonHandler() {
    console.log(paypal);
    paypal.Buttons(this.payPalConfig).render('#paypal-button');
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<div>
  <button ion-button (click)="payButtonHandler()">Pay with Paypal</button>
</div>
<div id="paypal-button"></div>

</ion-content>
```